# Communications link failure when connecting to remote MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to make a Java program communicate with a MySQL server hosted with A Small Orange. The IP and port they provided me with are 129.121.106.234:3306. The user has been given full permissions to the database, and in my CPanel I've allowed all remote hosts to connect to the MySQL database by adding the access host "%".

I'm using Eclipse, and I've downloaded and added the JDBC driver to the build path.

As near as I can tell, the user I'm trying to use has full permissions to the database, and the MySQL server is open to any request from any IP. I've also tried my admin MySQL credentials, with the same error, so I'm decently confident the issue is with my code. Not absolutely sure though, since I'm not hosting the MySQL server myself.

My code:

```
package com.package.IPBounce;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*
     * Isaac the Support Ninja says: The MySQL port is 3306. The IP you use
     * is 129.121.106.234.
     */
    URL whatismyip;
    String IP;
    try {
        whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip.openStream()));
        IP = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(IP);

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

                    //this is just testing code until I get the connection working
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://129.121.106.234:3306/db_name";
        String user = "user_name";
        String password = "small_password";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);//error is on this line
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

The error text:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has  not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1137)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.package.IPBounce.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
... 15 more
```

Edit: I found the solution. My hosting service was blocking the MySQL requests at the firewall. Cleared that up, now it works wonderfully.

Comment: Is the host able to monitor traffic and verify you're making a tcp/3306 connection? I was not able to connect to that port on that IP, so "open to any request from any IP" is either incorrect, or the server itself isn't currently reachable.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see as a possible issue is the "newInstance()" call. Try remove that and see if that works.

From:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

To:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered here:

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Please try the steps in the accepted answer and see if your issue is resolved.

From my experience, I had this issue when my MySql configuration file allowed only `localhost` access. Replace localhost with the ip address.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I've tried all of those steps, and none of them work. Should have put that in, sorry.